# Laravel pagination - keep params?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

So I have a 'search results' page in Laravel, which paginates its results.

I'm passing into the view a `$search` object which contains the terms etc, like so:

```
  return view('pages.search', [
    'listings' => $listings, 
    'search' => $search
  ]);
```

This works fine on the first page, but on any other page the object disappears. As per the docs, I've tried to do this where I render the page links:

```
{!! $listings->appends(['search' => $search])->render() !!}
```

...and it appends a bunch of weird stuff that clearly is not my $search object:

```
/search?search%5Bincrementing%5D=1&search%5Bexists%5D=0&search%5BwasRecentlyCreated%5D=0&search%5Btimestamps%5D=1&page=2
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, I'm an idiot. This did the trick:
`{!! $listings->appends(Input::except('page'))->links() !!}`